# Rewrite from sub domain without change url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Structure
 public_html
  -.htaccess
  -subdomain
  -codefolder
```

The task that the **subdomain** should look in **codefolder** but did not change **URL**. Is it possible?

I try

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.example.com
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdomain.example.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/ [L]
```

But it certainly leads to a change in the URL, but I do not need it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question through a symlink.

```
ln -s  /path-to/subdomain codefolder
```

and in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) /example/public/%1 [L]
```

This is not the best option, but my hosting does not have access to the Apache configuration.